# R language iterate over R object

Tags: r, loops

I have an unknown R object that prints like this.  How do I iterate over the values and print them?

```
    print(myRobject)

[[1]]
                  theTicker                  thePeriodEnded
                     "MSFT"                    "31-03-2013"
              theRevenueRaw                 theNetIncomeRaw
                    "20489"                          "6055"
theEarningsPerShareBasicRaw    theWeightedAveSharesBasicRaw
                     "0.72"                          "8364"
```

theCashDivDeclPerCommonShareRaw     theNetCashFromOperationsRaw
                         "0.23"                          "9666"

```
[[2]]
                  theTicker                  thePeriodEnded
                     "XXXX"                    "31-03-2013"
              theRevenueRaw                 theNetIncomeRaw
                    "20489"                          "6055"
theEarningsPerShareBasicRaw    theWeightedAveSharesBasicRaw
                     "0.72"                          "8364"
```

theCashDivDeclPerCommonShareRaw     theNetCashFromOperationsRaw
                         "0.23"                          "9666"

Dean and Metrics, here are some results.
How do I separate "theTicker" from "MSFT", so I can (eventually) loop?

str(myRobject)

```
List of 1
$ : Named chr [1:8] "MSFT" "31-03-2013" "20489" "6055" ...
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:8] "theTicker" "thePeriodEnded" "theRevenueRaw" "theNetIncomeRaw" ...
```

myRobject[[1]]

```
WORKS - returns just list item 1
```

myRobject[[1]]["theTicker"]

```
theTicker
"MSFT"
```

str(myRobject[[1]]["theTicker"])

```
Named chr "MSFT"
- attr(*, "names")= chr "theTicker"
```

require(plyr)
Loading required package: plyr
ldply(myRobject, identity)

```
theTicker thePeriodEnded theRevenueRaw theNetIncomeRaw
1      MSFT     31-03-2013         20489            6055
2      XXXX     31-03-2013         20489            6055
theEarningsPerShareBasicRaw theWeightedAveSharesBasicRaw
1                        0.72                         8364
2                        0.72                         8364
theCashDivDeclPerCommonShareRaw theNetCashFromOperationsRaw
1                            0.23                        9666
2                            0.23                        9666
```

out[[1]]["theTicker"][1]

```
theTicker
"MSFT"
```

out[[1]]["theTicker"][2]

```
<NA>
NA
```

out[[1]]["theTicker"]["1"]

```
<NA>
NA
```

out[[1]]["theTicker"][["1"]]

```
ERROR
```

out[[1]]["theTicker"]$1

```
ERROR
```

out[[1]]["theTicker"][1,1]

```
Error in out[[1]]["theTicker"][1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

out[[1]]["theTicker"][1]

```
theTicker
"MSFT"
```

out[[1]]["theTicker"][1][1]

```
theTicker
"MSFT"
```

out[[1]]["theTicker"][1][2]

```
<NA>
 NA
```

out[[1]]["theTicker"][1][1][1]

```
theTicker
"MSFT"
```

do.call(rbind,myRobject)

```
theTicker thePeriodEnded theRevenueRaw theNetIncomeRaw
[1,] "MSFT"    "31-03-2013"   "20489"       "6055"
[2,] "XXXX"    "31-03-2013"   "20489"       "6055"
theEarningsPerShareBasicRaw theWeightedAveSharesBasicRaw
[1,] "0.72"                      "8364"
[2,] "0.72"                      "8364"
theCashDivDeclPerCommonShareRaw theNetCashFromOperationsRaw
[1,] "0.23"                          "9666"
[2,] "0.23"                          "9666"
```

ticker<-list(myRobject[[1]][1],myRobject[[2]][1])

ticker

```
[[1]]
theTicker
"MSFT"

[[2]]
theTicker
"XXXX"
```

period<-list(myRobject[[1]][2],myRobject[[2]][2])

```
period

[[1]]
thePeriodEnded
"31-03-2013"

[[2]]
thePeriodEnded
"31-03-2013"
```

Again, ow do I separate "theTicker" from "MSFT", so I can (eventually) loop?

Comment: I don't get it - you seem to be able to `print` it just fine. What do you actually want as a result?

Comment: `str` is useful when you have an unknown object & want to figure out what it is

Answer (score 3):

There's a `plyr` solution:

```
require(plyr)
ldply(myRobject, identity)
```

This calls 'identity' on each list element and returns the results as a data frame. This solution is neither particularly fast, nor robust: it will fail if the list elements have different numbers of columns. However, I like it because

- it is simple
- `plyr` is great for lots of tasks, so I think it is helpful to be in the habit of looking for `plyr` solutions wherever I can.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` or other `xxapply` functions to iterate throgh a list. But here it is simpler to transform it to a matrix:

```
do.call(rbind,ll)
     theTicker thePeriodEnded
[1,] "MSFT"    "31-03-2013"  
[2,] "ORCL"    "31-03-2012"
```

Comment: Similarly, `require(plyr); ldply(myRobject, identity)`

Comment: @DrewSteen I think this should not be a comment under this answer... Maybe you can post it as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ticker<-list(myRobject[[1]][1],myRobject[[2]][1])
period<-list((myRobject[[1]][2],myRobject[[2]][2])
```

Now you can use the ticker and period as an inputs in `Map` function

```
Map(function(x,y) your function, ticker period)
```